# Javascript - Copiar conteúdo de um <span> para área de transferência ao clicar em um <button>

Tags: javascript

> Estou criando um gerador de CPF, o qual quando a pessoa gera, aparece uma opção de "Copiar", porém gostaria de saber como implementar a funcionalidade de copiar o conteúdo que é apresentado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Exemplo Código HTML:

```
<span id="numerosx">56262662</span>
<button id="btcopiar">COPIAR</button>
```

Obs: Javascript Puro.

Comment: Nada haver, kkkkkk...

Comment: `console.log(document.getElementById('numerosx').innerHTML)` resolve?

Comment: Não entendi bem, kkkkk, você poderia responder :) Não sou muito bom com JS.

Comment: @rray responde aí :)

Comment: Era isso que vc queria? pela pergunta deu a entender outra coisa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Veja:*

```js
document.querySelector("button").onclick = function() {
    var element= document.getElementById('numerosx');
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNode(element);
    window.getSelection().addRange(range);
    document.execCommand("copy");
};
```

```html
<span id="numerosx">56262662</span>
<button id="btcopiar">COPIAR</button>
```

Comment: Amigo, ele é funcional, porém quando coloquei aqui não funcionou. Coloquei exatamente como você respondeu. Seria algo que você esqueceu? Não entendo bem de JS...

Comment: Sim, funciona de boa. Não está funcionando é no meu site. Rsrsrs, acho que deve tá dendo problema com outro script externo. Você não sabe como "forçar" isso? :(

Comment: Sim, acho que não vai funcionar na página que tenho aqui não.

Comment: Eu não sei, tem algo que tá bloqueando, deve tá vindo de scripts externos, aí eu não sei como fazer funcionar :(

Comment: Só se tivesse algo que o force funcionar, que force a copia :(

Comment: Aqui não funcionou...

Comment: @MatheusVitor conseguiu?